# Redirect App to Facebook Tab after granting permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to redirect my app to the installed Facebook tab after granting permissions, I configured the getLoginUrl to use the page tab url as the redirect_url like this:

```
$params = array('redirect_uri' => 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage/xxxxxx?v=app_xxx');
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

But when I go to my App Tab it displays that the URL is not valid for the configuration, however if I use the getLoginUrl withour parameters it redirects to my app, but hosted on my website (obviously I dont what this)

Any idea?